# Hide soft input keyboard when dialog closes

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-dialog

I'm opening a `Dialog` from within an `Activity`. When the dialog opens, I call

```java
((InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED, InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
```

The problem is, when I close the dialog either by hitting a cancel button or clicking outside the dialog, the keyboard switches to a text keyboard and doesn't go away util I click the hardware back button. How can I dismiss the keyboard when the dialog is dismissed, and focus is returned to the previous window?

Comment: any solution on this?

Answer (score 10):

in **AndroidManifest.xml**, set this property in your **Activity** that show the **Dialog**

> android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"

Note! not **stateHiddent**, is **stateAlwaysHidden**. It will automatically hide soft keyboard on Dismiss of Dialog.

Hope that save your life.

Comment: Thanks @Weiliang Chik, you saved my time

Comment: @ParmarSubhash, not your life?

Answer (score 1):

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(EllipticalActivity.this);
builder.setTitle("title")
       .setMessage("message")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setNegativeButton("Close", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
               InputMethodManager inputManager = 
                   (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
               inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                                                    InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
               dialog.cancel();
           }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Comment: Looking at your code, this will only close the keyboard if I click a button. I'd like it to close for more than one reason: clicking a button, clicking outside, or the dialog completing its task. It makes more sense to just detect when the dialog _is_ dismissed, rather than white-listing all the possible ways the window can _be_ dismissed.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that this method of the activity can be useful to you.

```
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if(hasFocus)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "has focus", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        // write code to remove keyboard
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, solution was to put keyboard hide in dialog dismiss

```
dialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        if (view != null) {
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

From Activity onCreateView() method you can do this:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN)
```

Or In Manifest xml

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```

It will automatically hide soft keyboard on Dismiss of Dialog